# How to call method based on class type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

We have BaseSchemaBuilder and SingleLineSchemaBuilder classes working on the following interfaces:

```
interface BaseSchema {
  label: string;
}

interface SingleLineSchema extends BaseSchema {
  maxLength: string
}

class BaseSchemaBuilder<T extends BaseSchema>{
  constructor(protected schema: T){}

  setLabel(label: string) {
    this.schema.label = label;
    return this;
  }
}

class SingleLineSchemaBuilder extends BaseSchemaBuilder<SingleLineSchema>{
  constructor(schema: SingleLineSchema){
    super(schema)
  }

  setMaxLength(maxLength: string) {
    this.schema.maxLength = maxLength;
    return this;
  }
}
```

So now we have common method like this.

We want to generate schema based on SchemaBuilder type. We have SchemaSetter, which is called on update of the component. And we are able to know which is current type.

```
class SchemaSetter{

onSetLabel(label){
/*
So here we able to call setLabel on both BaseSchemaBuilder and SingleLineSchemaBuilder classes.

*/
}

onSetMaxLength(length){
/*
So here how to call setMaxLength based on SchemaBuilder type.
If we strict to SingleLineSchemaBuilder, we don't have setMaxLength in BaseSchemaBuilder.

*/
}

}
```

So here how to call setMaxLength based on SchemaBuilder type.
If we strict to SingleLineSchemaBuilder, we don't have setMaxLength in BaseSchemaBuilder.
How to ignore this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wQKP7m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.

Comment: Sure @jcalz , Will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to achieve this is to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). It allows you to verify the type of the variable and acts similar to casting the variable in other languages.

For example, you may define the type guard like this:

```
function isSingleLineBuilder(input: BaseSchemaBuilder<any>): input is SingleLineSchemaBuilder{
  return typeof (input as any)['setMaxLength'] === 'function'
}
```

Then you can use it in you `SchemaBuilder`.

```
class SchemaSetter {

  constructor(private schemaBuilder: BaseSchemaBuilder<any>){}

  onSetLabel(label: string) {
    this.schemaBuilder.setLabel(label);
  }

  onSetMaxLength(length: string) {
    if(isSingleLineBuilder(this.schemaBuilder)){
      this.schemaBuilder.setMaxLength(length);
    }
  }
}
```

Within the context of the `if` statement the `schemaBuilder` will be of type `SingleLineSchemaBuilder`.

You can see a working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#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-ZyPtnMgNdhliIDH9kql0plchwAG5wSClDy2qBqnQa+u6g1GmqCKjJPMNWYtWYU2ycalwvkDel1rXXYbLRptfttSqCzvIbs4tlMolSSODro9XrAGCKjAy04QetZOmo55T6CVWELPr8obXzVXaAzsDh9mWFqbpejgIVC1HwQA)

**Offtopic**

The fact you may need to use a cast / type guard means that you may want to reconsider your design.

What should happen for example if the max length is exceeded in `SingleLineSchemaBuilder`? If it will throw some error in that case it will introduce a new invariant which might brake the Liskov principle.

Also, when the client is passing the `SchemaBuilder` to the `SchemaSetter` he can see that the `SchemaSetter` is accepting objects of some base class. He may not expect the `SchemaSetter` to access the `setMaxLength` method. This kind of brakes the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Apokralipsa . I redesigned entire architecture. Thank you.